# ASP.Net MVC TryUpdateModel() equivalent for using in a Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

TryUpdateModel is one of the methods in System.Web.Mvc,but I need to use it in windows application which does not have this library.
Any similar method in EF or other suggestions so that I can update an entity without matching fields one by one with the target model?

Comment: very Important question. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions but finally I wrote my own method via reflection which worked perfect for me as follows:

```
        public void TryUpdateModel<T>(T existingModel, T newModel)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = existingModel.GetType()
                                                .GetProperties()
                                                .Where(pi => !(pi.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
                                                .ToArray();
        foreach (var item in properties)
        {
            var propName = item.Name;
            if (item.PropertyType.IsSealed && item.PropertyType.IsSerializable && item.Name != existingModel.GetType().Name + "Id")
            {
                var newValue = db.Entry(newModel).Property(propName).CurrentValue;
                db.Entry(existingModel).Property(propName).CurrentValue = newValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

It gets 2 models (as they are generic classes but should be the same) in which first one is the model fetched from database and second one is what submitted from the UI form.
It updates property values from newModel to existingModel except navigation properties and primary key so that entity framework realizes that values are changed and have to be updated.

Comment: An answer shouldn't consist only of a link to an external resource. Copy the relevant information into your answer so that the answer is still helpful if the external resource is gone.